# Hosting animated GIF banners on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, pictures

I have uploaded some animated GIF banners to our S3 account and when we use the web url provided by S3 and try to view the banners in a browser, instead of display the banners in the browsers, I get prompted to download the banner image. Why is this?

When I uploaded a JPG image in the same S3 bucket and try to view it with a browser, I don't have this problem?

How do we solve this problem? We would like to syndicate our GIF banners through various affiliate sites. Could this cause issues at their end? The full URL of the banner is in this format banners.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/dining-728x90.gif. Even when we use the CNAME version we have the same issue. The CNAME version is banners.mydomain.com/dining-728x90.gif.

Comment: Just so you know, they'll still work fine in `<img>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a proper mime type not being added for gif files.  Add it or change the current mime type for that file to the appropriate gif mime type rather than binary/octet and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: To follow-up, here is a related question with a solution regarding changing the mimetype on files on Amazon S3 from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694748/mime-type-for-uploaded-files-on-s3